# Symfony 4 how to redirect anonymous user back to the home page?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am using json_login for the login form, so it's done by ajax on a modal, not an actual login page.

Instead of showing the 403 access denied page when trying to access a restricted url, how can i redirect the user back to the base / ?

EDIT: What I am saying is, the user logs in with json_login that's all fine. But if I am logged out and try to access a secured area as an anonymous user it just shows an Access Denied page, I need it to not show that and redirect to the home page.

So if i am Anonymous user and I try to access a secured area like /admin all I get is a horrible access denied page. I want that to just redirect to the home page, no matter if the user is logged in as a user without the correct permissions or anonymous user tries to access a restricted area - not just leave them on a dead access denied page.

I can't find anything that explains how to accomplish this, access_denied_url doesn't work for anonymous users.

HERE IS MY security.yaml:

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    access_denied_url: /
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [app_user_username, app_user_email]
        app_user_username:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
        app_user_email:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            user_checker: App\Security\LoginChecker
            provider: chain_provider
            json_login:
              check_path: /login
            logout:
              path: /logout
              target: /

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - {path: ^/extranet/.*, roles: [ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_DELTA]}
        - {path: ^/customer/^register, roles: [ROLE_CUSTOMER]}
        - {path: ^/account/.*, roles: [ROLE_CUSTOMER,ROLE_DELTA,ROLE_CLIENT]}
        - {path: ^/vehicles/auction/bid/[0-9]*, roles: [ROLE_CUSTOMER]}
        - {path: ^/vehciles/auction/buy/[0-9]*, roles: [ROLE_CUSTOMER]}
        - {path: ^/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15
```

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-failure)?

Comment: @ehymel Yes but it doesn't say what I want. What I am saying is, the user logs in with json_login that's all fine. But if I am logged out and try to access a secured area as an anonymous user it just shows an Access Denied page, I need it to not show that and redirect to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using javascript when you get the response from ajax request, for example :

window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

Comment: What I am saying is, the user logs in with json_login that's all fine. But if I am logged out and try to access a secured area as an anonymous user it just shows an Access Denied page, I need it to not show that and redirect to the home page.